# C++. Вопросы по перегрузке

Tags: c++, классы

У меня перегрузка + и << работает, но для этого мне нужно писать все с указателями (*C=*A+*B; cout << *C). Что нужно изменить, чтобы работало без них?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#define N 5

class Fraction
{

private:
    int chys,
        zn;
public:
    Fraction()
    {
        this->chys = 0;
        this->zn = 0;
    }

    Fraction(int chys, int zn)
    {
        this->chys = chys;
        this->zn = zn;
    }

    Fraction(const Fraction &obj)
    {
        this->chys = obj.chys;
        this->zn = obj.zn;
    }

    int GetChys() { return chys; }
    int GetZn() { return zn; }
    void setFraction(int x, int y) { chys = x; zn = y; }

    int CommonZn(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        int q = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 1; q != 1; i++)
        {
            if ((i % A->zn == 0) && (i % B->zn == 0))
            {
                q = 1;
                A->chys *= (i / A->zn);
                B->chys *= (i / B->zn);
            }
        }
        A->zn = i - 1;
        B->zn = i - 1;
        this->zn = i - 1;
        return i - 1;
    }

    int skor(int *chys, int *zn)
    {
        int i = 0, b = 0;
        if (*chys > *zn) { b = *chys; }
        else (b = *zn);
        for (i = b; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (*chys%i == 0 && *zn%i == 0)
            {
                *chys = *chys / i;
                *zn = *zn / i;
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }

    void comperizon(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        if (A->chys > B->chys) { cout << endl; cout << "Перший дріб більший за другий" << endl; }
        else if (A->chys == B->chys) { cout << endl; cout << "Дроби однакові" << endl; }
        else if (A->chys < B->chys) { cout << endl; cout << "Другий дріб більший за перший" << endl; }
    }

    void addition(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = A->chys + B->chys;
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nСума дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void subtraction(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = A->chys - B->chys;
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nРізниця дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void multiplication(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = (A->chys * B->chys);
        this->zn = (A->zn * B->zn);
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nДобуток дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void division(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = (A->chys * B->zn);
        this->zn = (A->zn * B->chys);
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nЧастка дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    Fraction& operator=(Fraction &second)
    {
        cout << "operator =" << endl;
        chys = second.chys; zn = second.zn;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator == (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        cout << "operator ==" << endl;
        return (this->chys == obj.chys);
    }

    bool operator >= (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        cout << "operator >=" << endl;
        return (this->chys >= obj.chys);
    }

    bool operator <= (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        cout << "operator <=" << endl;
        return (this->chys <= obj.chys);
    }

    friend Fraction& operator +(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second)
    {
        cout << "operator +" << endl;
        return *new Fraction( first.chys + second.chys, first.zn );
    }

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const Fraction &fr);

    ~Fraction() { }
};

ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const Fraction &fr)
{
    out << fr.chys << "/" << fr.zn;
    return out;
}

    int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("color f0");
    system("cls");
    int chys1, zn1, chys2, zn2;

    cout << "Введіть перший дріб = ";
    cin >> chys1;
    cin.ignore(1);
    cin >> zn1;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Введіть другий дріб = ";
    cin >> chys2;
    cin.ignore(1);
    cin >> zn2;
    cout << endl;

    Fraction *A = new Fraction(chys1, zn1);
    Fraction *B = new Fraction(chys2, zn2);
    Fraction *C = new Fraction(*A);

    C->CommonZn(A, B);
    C->comperizon(A, B);
    C->addition(A, B);
    C->subtraction(A, B);
    C->multiplication(A, B);
    C->division(A, B);
    cout << endl;

    *C = *A + *B;
    cout << *C;
    cout << endl;

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: + вопрос по перегрузке оператора сложения
У меня он только с указателями работает, можно как то исправить? Или так и нужно?

Comment: Что такое "не получается"? Где в вопросе осмысленное описание проблемы?

Comment: @AnT ошибку с VS скинул чуть выше вашего вопроса

Comment: Ну так почему это болтается в комментарии, а не в вопросе? И как мы должны понять, в какой строке вы получили эту ошибку?

Comment: Что вы вообще пытались сделать этим `out << fr.GetChys << "/" << fr.GetZn;`??? Что такое `fr.GetChys`? Если это попытка вызова функции, то функции в С++ вызываются оператором `()`, Где у вас здесь оператор `()`?

Comment: @AnT исправил, новая ошибка

Comment: С перегрузкой только разбираюсь, смотрел туториал, там у рассказывающего все было в паблике, поэтому у него работало f.chys и f.zn

Comment: `f.chys` - это переменая. У вас в коде - не `f.chys`, а `f.GetChys`. `f.GetChys` - это функция, а не переменная. Вы понимаете разницу между переменными и функциями? К перегрузке этот вопрос никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @AnT я прекрасно понимаю, но я  (наварное плохо) спросил, если у меня поля класса в private, как мне использовать их при этой перегрузке?

Comment: 1. Можно сделать перегрузку "другом" - тогда она получит доступ напрямую к приватным полям. 2. Можно завести функции-геттеры, как это сделали вы. Но еще раз: функции в С++  вызываются оператором `()`. Сколько можно это повторять?

Comment: @AnT почему-то думал, что friend функция будет иметь доступ к protected, но не к private. Спасибо за помощь! Вы ответ комментарием написали, как вам репутацию поднять, или что тут сделать нужно? Только недавно зарегестрировался

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
out << fr.GetChys << "/" << fr.GetZn;
```

Вы забыли указать, что `GetChys` и `GetZn` - функции

```
out << fr.GetChys() << "/" << fr.GetZn();
```

Далее в вашем коде:

```
friend Fraction& operator +(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second)
    {
        cout << "operator +" << endl;
        return *new Fraction( first.chys + second.chys, first.zn );
    }
```

Так же вы возвращаете и принимаете ссылки на объекты, если вы хотите получать и передавать их по значению, необходимо реализовать конструктор копирования.

Comment: `return *new` - жесть вообще-то - память течёт...

Comment: `friend` просто так убирать нельзя. Если его убрать, придется убрать первый параметр `operator+` и убрать из тела все `first.`.

Comment: Указывать этот оператор как `friend` нужно потому, что  ему нужен доступ к приватным полям класса, а не потому, что он перегружается вне класса. Если бы доступа к приватным полям класса не нужно было бы, то и никакого `friend` не нужно было бы, несмотря на то оператор что он перегружается вне класса.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я же правильно понимаю, что `return *new` возвращает указатель, и в данном случае он лишний?

Comment: @AlexanderEASTEV, неправильно понимаешь. Указатель возвращает просто `return new`.